# Plotting, Integrating two variable function with cross-restricted domain

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

[image]

Hello, I have two problems.

the first is plotting 3D function, the domain is "0<x<y<1". (I could find examples like integrating function with domain 0<x<1, 0<y<1, but I could not find examples for a<x<y<b.)

the second is just Intergrating the funcntion below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the plot you can use [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction), which takes a pure function which takes x, y, and z values::

```
Plot3D[1/(1-x),{x,0,1},{y,0,1},RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z},x<y]]
```

[image]

Your second issue is fixed by spelling [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) properly (notice that `Intergrate` is in blue, meaning that it is an undefined global variable), and by swapping the order of integration:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[x^2+y^2]/Pi, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[1-x^2], Sqrt[1-x^2]}]
```

> 1/3

Comment: Also, `Plot3D[1/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}, {y, x, 1}]`

Comment: Wow... I had so many mistakes, really really thanks.